# FInding the most frequent number only using for loop

Tags: python

I know there are multiple questions asked reguarding finding the most frequent numbers and how many times they have been repeated. However,  I have a problem that requires to sole the question only using for loop, if, etc.

I'm not allowed to use .count, dic, arrary or any other fancy functions.

```
My_list=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,7,8,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8]
```

The answer that is required to print would be

```
1, 8times 8, 8times
```

I know it may be a pain to use only for loop, but it's killing me and i'm craving for hlep :(

Comment: I dont think it's sensibly possible without a dict. You'll have to make a lot of variables and the code will be awful

Comment: Please see [How to Ask a Homework Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).  Simply dumping your assignment here is not acceptable, and may constitute a violation of your school's academic standards.

Comment: Also check [can someone help me?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This suggests a range of needs too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I know :( but te professor thought it was fine to give as an assignment..

Comment: What constitutes "fancy"? Can you use `set()` and `max()`?

Comment: surprisingly no. I'm not allowed to even use set() or max()....

Comment: @roganjosh yeah exactly, no need for dicts if the goal is just to find one max number, but to get both 1 and 8 as the solution for this problem more or less requires a dict (at least, for sensible solutions)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. What's your question? Please [edit] to clarify. If you're looking for help writing the code, we're not going to do it all for you, but we can help if you get stuck. Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) See [ask] if you want more tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of questions that exist will practice iterative and list. I do not think so this is a good practice. For your pain, I thought to provide you a little bit of a messy answer (messy means a lot of use of variables).

You have not mentioned **length of your list.** Therefore, I have created this code to work with any range.

## Code with comments

```
My_list=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,7,8,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8]

list1 = []
list2 = []
list3 = []

c = 0
k = 1
y = 1

while y == 1: # Use while loop until all objects read and store in another lists
  for i in My_list: # read oblectsa in My_list one by one
    if i == k:
      list1.append(k) # append all same digits into list1
  
  list2.append(len(list1)) # Get the length of list1 that have same digits and store it in list2
  list3.append(list1[0]) # Get the first value of list1 that have same digits and store it in list2
  list1 = [] # Reset the list one for store next same digits

  k = k + 1

  if k == My_list[-1] + 1: # get the value of last digit of the list 
    y = 0

m = 0

for j in list2: # use this for loop to get final outcome
  print(m, ",", j, "times", list3[m], ",", j, "times")
  m = m + 1
```

---

## Code without comments

```
My_list=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,7,8,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8]

list1 = []
list2 = []
list3 = []

c = 0
k = 1
y = 1

while y == 1:
  for i in My_list:
    if i == k:
      list1.append(k)
  
  list2.append(len(list1))
  list3.append(list1[0])
  list1 = []

  k = k + 1

  if k == My_list[-1] + 1:
    y = 0

m = 0

for j in list2:
  print(m, ",", j, "times", list3[m], ",", j, "times")
  m = m + 1
```

**Output -:**

```
0 , 8 times 1 , 8 times
1 , 3 times 2 , 3 times
2 , 1 times 3 , 1 times
3 , 1 times 4 , 1 times
4 , 1 times 5 , 1 times
5 , 2 times 6 , 2 times
6 , 3 times 7 , 3 times
7 , 8 times 8 , 8 times
```

**Note -:**
You can use `print(list2)` and `print(list3)` end of the code to see what happens. And also try to understand the code by deleting part by part.